# Can the predicate "is a 2-cycle" be defined in the first-order language of groups?

Tags: group-theory, logic

Does there exist a unary predicate $\varphi$ definable in the first order-language of groups having the following property?

> For all sets $X$ and all $f \in \mathrm{Sym}(X),$ we have: $f$ is a 2-cycle iff the group $(\mathrm{Sym}(X),\circ)$ models that $\varphi$ holds for $f$.

Note in particular that we're not allowed to evaluate $f \in \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ at some $x \in X$, since evaluation at $x \in X$ is not part of the language.

*Remark.* Clearly, if $\varphi$ holds for $f,$ then we must have $f^2 = e.$ However, this is insufficient, since $f$ could be a composition of disjoint 2-cycles.

Comment: What precisely is the structure you are working on? I assume it is $(\mathrm{Sym}(X),\circ)$, where $\circ$ indicates composition, so we do not have access to the elements of $X$, right? (So that we cannot really talk of $f(x)$ for some $x\in X$ or quantify over elements of $X$.) You may want to make this explicit, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thanks I edited to make it clearer. Please comment regarding whether or not the ambiguity has been dealt with sufficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I would suggest to add the parenthetical remark in my first comment, so that there is no room for confusion.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, done.

Comment: If $h:G \to H$ is an isomorphism of (symmetric) groups such that $g$ is a 2-cycle but $h(g)$ is not, then that would be bad right? Take $X$ to have 6 points, then such an isomorphism exists.

Comment: It's easy to see that a permutation group is (group-wise) isomorphic to a permutation group acting on a bigger set with every cycle doubled. So any statement that single out $f$ as a 2-cycle must involve something to do with element of $X$ too. For example, given a permutation group on 3 element you can obtain a permutation group on 6 element, wherein a cycle, say (1 2) get mapped to (1 2)(4 5). Also, this link might be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Isomorphisms

Answer (score 3):

As automorphisms preserve first-order formulas, one can prove that such a $\varphi$ doesn't exist by sending a $2$-cycle of $\mathfrak S_6$ to some non-2-cycle element via some automorphism.

There is no smaller counter-example, as automorphisms of $\mathfrak S_n$ are all inner for $n\leq 5, n\neq 2$, and hence send 2-cycles on 2-cycles (and the case $n=2$ is trivial since the only element of order 2 is a 2-cycle).

Comment: This has the makings of an excellent answer, but could you give some idea about how to construct such an automorphism of $\mathfrak{S}_6$? An abstract argument proving the existence of such an automorphism would also be acceptable.